# Vue component not showing child text node when using render function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to do an editable component with Vue 2. It supposed to use the `contenteditable` attribute in any tag, replacing a normal input. I want to give it a placeholder functionality in order to show a value when none is provided by the user, but I can't seem to get it working.

I'm watching the current value of the component and setting `data.isEmpty` to `true` when no user content is present. The component should then show the placeholder value, but currently it shows nothing.

If I `console.log` the result of the `render` method, it will show the placeholder child node was instantiated correctly, but for some reason it just won't show on the final HTML.

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dy27fa8t/

And an embedded snippet for those who prefer it:

```js
Vue.component('editable-content', {
  props: {
    initial: {
      type: String
    },
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: this.initial,
      isEmpty: this.initial === ''
    }
  },
  render: function(createElement) {
    const self = this
    return createElement(
      'div', {
        attrs: {
          contenteditable: true
        },
        on: {
          input: function(event) {
            self.value = event.target.innerHTML
            self.$emit('edited', event.target.value)
          }
        }
      },
      this.isEmpty ? this.placeholder : this.value
    )
  },
  watch: {
    value(to, from) {
      this.isEmpty = to === ''
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: [
    'editable-content'
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <editable-content initial="Initial value" placeholder="Placeholder" />
</div>
```

Comment: When you say, "when none is provided by the user" do you mean when there is no `initial` attribute bound on the component?

Comment: Well, that too. But I'm mostly referring to the user going to edit the element and deleting all characters. I'm basically trying to reproduce the placeholder on an HTML `input`, so when no value is set the placeholder shows up.

Comment: It has something to do with it re-using the DOM element and the DOM element having focus. What I mean is, if you change the value without it having focus (like with setTimeout) it sets the placeholder value. Likewise, if you add a unique `key` on each render, it will set the placeholder, but you lose focus on the DOM element.

Comment: I've tested this and you're right. Bummer. Sure hope there's a workaround, because losing focus on every edit sort of defeats the purpose of having this component...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I settled for a mixed JS and CSS solution using the `:empty` pseudo-class. A Vue-only workaround just seemed too unwieldy, so this felt like a healthy compromise. I don't even feel the need to keep track of the `value` anymore.

Worth noting that with single-file components I can use scoped CSS so it's even better as the CSS is essential to the components core functionality.

```js
Vue.component('editable-content', {
  props: {
    initial: {
      type: String
    },
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: this.initial
    }
  },
  render: function(createElement) {
    const self = this
    return createElement(
      'div', {
        attrs: {
          contenteditable: true,
          'data-placeholder': this.placeholder
        },
        on: {
          input: function(event) {
            self.$emit('edited', event.target.value)
          }
        }
      },
      this.value
    )
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: [
    'editable-content'
  ]
})
```

```css
[data-placeholder]:empty::after {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <editable-content initial="Initial value" placeholder="Placeholder" />
</div>
```

Comment: I think the CSS approach is the right choice. Wish I'd thought of it.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently rendering a `contenteditable` doesn't work in the intuitive way. Instead, set the `innerHTML` directly with the placeholder when the content is empty. Then on `keydown` (before the input event), if the content is currently marked empty, remove the placeholder. On `keyup` (after the input event), if the div still has no content, mark it empty again (this is so things like shift key don't clear the placeholder).

I took the liberty of making it `v-model` compatible and styling the placeholder.

```js
Vue.component('editable-content', {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String
    },
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isEmpty: this.value === ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setEmpty() {
      this.$el.innerHTML = `<div contenteditable="false" class="placeholder">${this.placeholder}</div>`;
      this.isEmpty = true;
    },
    clearEmpty() {
      this.$el.innerHTML = '';
      this.isEmpty = false;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if (this.$el.innerHTML === '') {
      this.setEmpty();
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value(newValue) {
      if (newValue === '') {
        this.setEmpty();
      }
    }
  },
  render: function(createElement) {
    return createElement(
      'div', {
        attrs: {
          contenteditable: true
        },
        on: {
          keydown: () => {
            if (this.isEmpty) {
              this.clearEmpty();
            }
          },
          input: (event) => {
            this.$emit('input', event.target.textContent);
          },
          keyup: () => {
            if (this.$el.innerHTML === '') {
              this.setEmpty();
            }
          }
        }
      },
      this.value
    )
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    startingBlank: '',
    editedValue: 'initial value'
  },
  components: [
    'editable-content'
  ]
})
```

```css
.placeholder {
  color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <editable-content v-model="startingBlank" placeholder="Placeholder"></editable-content>
  <editable-content v-model="editedValue" placeholder="Placeholder"></editable-content>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this truly works as I originally intended. On the other hand, it feels a bit overblown for what was supposed to be just a quick-fire substitute to ordinary HTML. I've posted my own answer now for the sake of comparison, since it's a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pass the `initial` prop into the component it will be undefined. So the check you should make is to see if is undefined:

```
data() {
    return {
      value: this.initial,
      isEmpty: typeof this.initial === 'undefined'
    }
  },
```

Comment: This doesn't solve his problem; just the problem I asked about in the comments.

Comment: It's a fair point and I need to fix it, but @BertEvans is right in that it doesn't solve the actual problem.